# I'm new to Json rest full services , how to get methods from json rest service? and how to Parse values to method in api using C# console applications

Tags: console

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    const string url = "https://test-api.abccc.com/api/Relayxxx.apixxxx?__token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

    var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    httpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/json";
    httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

    /* using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
    {
        string json = "{\"user\":\"xxxx\"," +
                      "\"password\":\"yyyy\"}";

        streamWriter.Write(json);
        streamWriter.Flush();
        streamWriter.Close();
    }*/

    var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

Please help me how to call functions using this api and how can i get values from specified functions and send values to specific function.